# Old style of Open/Save file dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I wonder how to display old style Open/Save file dialog in WinForms

this image is from VCE simulator , you can see there's no help button under Cancel button

[image]

I use this code to display the old style

```
        var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "VSE Exam Files (*.vce)|*.vce";
        sfd.ShowHelp = true;

        if ( sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
        {
            // Save document 
        }
```

[image]

but I don't want to display help button as it will not help you any way

I tried to switch my target .NET to 3.5, but still displays the new style

please help, am I missing some thing or what?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: maybe you add some help to your program so that when the user clicks the "Help" button it _is_ helpful. Or maybe just stick with the new style...is it really so awful?

Comment: I prefer old style save file dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `AutoUpgradeEnabled` to false instead of `ShowHelp`

```
var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "VSE Exam Files (*.vce)|*.vce";
sfd.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;

if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Save document 
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.autoupgradeenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> If this property is false, the FileDialog class will have a Windows
>   XP-style appearance and behavior on Windows Vista.

But on my system it works for Windows 7 as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you confirm this on Windows 10 too?

Comment: Glad it helped! I don't have Windows 10, so I can't confirm this on Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy
Just remove the parts you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign false to ShowHelp property :

```
    var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "VSE Exam Files (*.vce)|*.vce";
    sfd.ShowHelp = false;

    if ( sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
    {
        // Save document 
    }
```

Comment: it's false by default , I'm sure you even didn't test your code.

Comment: I tried with .net 4.5, 4.0 and 3.5, and all targets give your desired result with the ShowHelp property setting to false. I use windows 8.1.

Comment: I need the old style (XP) not the new style( Win 7 , 8 ..)

Answer (score 0):

```
  var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "VSE Exam Files (*.vce)|*.vce";
   // sfd.ShowHelp = true; no need this.

    if ( sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK )
    {
        // Save document 
    }
```